# searching for text file(s) and adding a line in them with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that can be used for the following task - search for certain text files and adding a text line in them - below the specified line. I am trying to use the following approach:

```
dir /s /a /b "%SystemDrive%\config*.ini" >> %userprofile%\temp.txt

for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%G IN (%userprofile%\temp.txt) DO (echo "%%G" >> %userprofile%\temp2.txt)

for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%G IN (%userprofile%\temp2.txt) DO (

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION     

    cd %%~dG%%~pG

    set inputFile=%%~nG%%~xG
    set outputFile=in.tmp
    set _strInsert=TCPPortNumber=870
    set _strFind=Random=No


        FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%inputFile%") DO (
        Echo %%A | Find "%_strFind%" && ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%" && ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
        IF [!errorlevel!] == [1] ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"

    )
    MOVE /Y "%outputFile%" "%inputFile%" && DEL /F /Q "%outputFile%"
```

Searching for `config*.ini` file(s) and writing results into `temp.txt`. Inserting quotes in case there are spaces in file paths for each line in `temp.txt` -> `temp2.txt`. Then for each file path in `temp2.txt` trying to insert `TCPPortNumber=870` below the line `Random=No`. If I use a "hard" file path this approach works, but with reading the files path from `temp2.txt` it gives me an error: `The system cannot find the file specified`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you delete the source file after successfully moving it (in the last line of code)? moving means the source file is no more anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION     
dir /s /a /b "%SystemDrive%\config*.ini" >> %userprofile%\temp.txt

set outputFile=in.tmp
set _strInsert=TCPPortNumber=870
set _strFind=Random=No
for /F "usebackqdelims=" %%G IN ("%userprofile%\temp.txt") DO (
 pushd %%~dpG
 FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%%~nxG") DO (
   ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
   Echo %%A | Find "%_strFind%" && >>"%outputFile%" ECHO %_strInsert%
 )
 MOVE /Y "%outputFile%" "%%~nxG"
 popd
) 
endlocal
```

The `setlocal` command should not be within the loop (unless it is matched by an `endlocal`) because it is not a switch, but establishes a frame, hence within the loop, `cmd` is establishing many nested local environments.

The three constant strings also should appear outside of the loop since their values do not change.

The second tempfile is not required as it is simply the first with each line quoted.

Since `%temp%` may contain spaces, the `for/f` ... %%G`needs to have the filename quoted, and consequently the`usebackq`option. The line is to be accepted into`%%G`in its entirity, so`delims=` is required, turning delimiters off.

The substring selectors may be combined, so `~dp` delivers the drive and path and `~nx` the name and extension.

In the original code, `inputfile` was being set up, but `%inputfile%` would be resolved to the value of `inputfile` **at the time the entire block (parenthesised sequence of lines) was parsed** not at run-time as the values change through execution of the code. This is the commonly-encountered `delayed expansion` problem - hundreds of references here on SO.

Since what appears to be needed is to insert a line after a particular line, we can simply reproduce each line then see whether the insertion is required, which simplifies the code. The placement of the redirector to before the `echo` overcomes the Windows-NT characteristic of selecting the device to be redirected by preceding the redirector with a device number.

Finally, `move /y` forces the replacement of the input file with the output file, so the output file will no longer exist

I haven't actually tried this code - you should execute it against a small copied subtree of the real data and evaluate it before relying on it.

---

small fix - changed original `cd` to `pushd` and added corresponding `popd` also removed superfluous `%`

PUSHD changes the current directory to that specified. POPD restores the original current-directory.

The extra `%` was a keying error (my normal machine is ill and I have to use the laptop - and boy, do I loathe the keyboard...)

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation! Appreciate your deep knowledge.The script is working if it is started from the drive where the files in search reside. In my case if I start the script from anywhere in %SystemDrive%, it is working fine. But if I start the script from different dirve than %SystemDrive% it says The system cannot find the file The system cannot find the file specified. Anyway your script suits my needs so for me it is working.What is the meaning of last percentage sign here MOVE /Y "%outputFile%" "%%~nxG%" - the script works with or without it?

Comment: Now it is a complete solution :). 10x